# Autolayout UIView Proportional height with Minimum height requirement

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-autolayout

I've created one Tab bar bottom view with proportional height related to main superview.
[image]

[image]

Whereas, tab bar bottom view height in 6+ -> 59, in 6 -> 53, in 5 -> 45 & in 4s -> 38. It's working proportionally fine. But what if I want this tab bar view's height should be minimum 46, at maximum it should work proportionally.

So based on the above heights on different devices, I want to achieve 6+ -> 59, 6 -> 53, 5 -> 46 & in 4s -> 46.

So what could be a possible solution in Auto layout to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add height constraint to more than 46 and its priority is 1000.And then set priority of top space constraint to 750.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an extra height constraint to the tab bar that is "greater than or equal to" 46.

Comment: will this work on its own or just create a layout which is only solvable on a screen size that doesn't currently exist? Do you need to do anything with priorities??

Comment: Hi @Wain, Ya it does concern with priority, I've tried Tometoyou answer, it was right but just didn't worked because both height had a equal 1000 priority. Lumialxk answer worked for me.

Comment: Damn it! Sorry I only just saw this. Yeah I wrote the answer off the top of my head and forgot about that.